# Must the with recursive statement always be on top of a with statements chain?

Tags: sql

Must with recursive always be on top of a with statements chain?

```
with a as(
    values(1)
), recursive t(n) as(
        values(1)
    union all
        select n+1
        from t
        where n<10
), u as(
    select *
    from t
)
select *
from u
```

In this example the with recursive goes wrong, and the statement with u is okay.

Comment: Are you using MS SQL Server, Postgresql or DB2?

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.  Someone with your reputation should know how to properly tag a question.  Tag with the database you are really using.

Comment: I am using them all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming postgresql, since of the 3 tags applied to the question this most closely reflects the syntax you have used - The first CTE doesn't have to be recursive, but if any CTE is recursive you have to define it at the start, so your example would become:

```
with recursive a as(
    values (1)
), t(n) as(
        values (1)
    union all
        select n+1
        from t
        where n<10
), u as(
    select *
    from t
)
select *
from u
```

**[Example on DB Fiddle](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=1beb60244198d6f984215c26d433e6b7)**

If the SQL Server tag was correct, then the answer is still that the recursive cte does not have to appear first, e.g.

```
with a as(
   select n from (values (1)) n (N)
), t(n) as(
        select n from (values (1)) n (N)
    union all
        select n+1
        from t
        where n<10
), u as(
    select *
    from t
)
select *
from u;
```

**[SQL Server example](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=e543192e349616e2c91dd09ddaf21b89)**